# Okhttp with different configuration

Tags: android, okhttp

I am building my OkHttp in the application class and holding a static reference to it. This way, I have one instance of OkHttp at any given time.

```
okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .cache(new Cache(context.getCacheDir(), 50 * 1024 * 1024))
                .addInterceptor(new HttpInterceptor())
                .build();
```

Now, I am making two kind of requests, one requires OAuth2 while the other require the API key and secret supplied as parameters to the request URL. I am [using an interceptor](https://gist.github.com/alex-shpak/da1e65f52dc916716930) for the request that requires an OAuth2.

So the problem is the latter request uses resorts to the interceptor for authentication, thus the request fails. Is there any way I can tell it "See, ignore the interceptor for this request"? Or do I need two instances of OkHttpClient?

Answer (score 1):

You will need two instances since after creating single instance wit interceptor attached to it will not ignore interceptor.
A hack can be to identify the url in the interceptor and ignore interceptor operation for that request.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest solution is to have a single OkHttp instance, but in your interceptor have the logic to decide how to authenticate.

This example [ServiceInterceptor.java](https://github.com/yschimke/oksocial/blob/master/src/main/java/com/baulsupp/oksocial/authenticator/ServiceInterceptor.java) checks each request and decides how to authenticate in a pluggable manner.  You could do something similar.

There are many benefits of this approach over different clients including

- reuse of the executor
- possibility that the connections can be coalesced for multiple hosts e.g. www.mysvc.com and api.mysvc.com
- Support for redirection across hosts